# Excel Import Data from Analysis Services - Date comes across as text

Tags: excel, deployment, ssas

I'm trying to use an (exercise) SSAS tabular model in Excel. The model contains a column `DATE`, in the Proporties window its Data Type is `Date` and the Date Format is `General`. When I import the data into Excel the date column seems to come across as text.

To import, I open Excel, go to Data -> Get External Data -> From Other Sources -> From Analysis Services

After the data gets imported, the `DATE` column contains text representations of the date. The "Group" section of the PivotTable Options tab is greyed out, and the sort only does A-Z. How do I get the data type to come across?

Comment: Do you just need a one time fix, or a long term solution?  If so, can you select the date column, right click it, select Format Cells and set the formatting to Date?  If that doesn't fix it, when you click on one of the date cells, does it have an apostrophe in front of the date?  If it does, can you select the column and replace the ' character with nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysis Services delivers attribute names always as strings. You could either build your own MDX query for the extract, instead of relying on the default import wizard query. In your custom query, you convert the name to measure of `Date` data type. This would look similar to this:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.MyDate AS
     CDate([DateDim].[DateAttrib].CurrentMember.Name)
SELECT { Measures.MyDate } ON COLUMNS,
       [DateDim].[DateAttrib].[DateAttrib].Members ON ROWS
  FROM [MyCubeName]
```

Or, within the tabular model, build a calculated column in date format, i. e. create a calculated column with the expression

```
DateValue([origDateColWhichIsText])
```

and make the original column invisible.

In all cases, converting from date strings to dates may be locale setting sensitive.

Comment: How do you do the second one, "within the tabular model, build a calculated column in date format"? The column's properties indicate that it has Data Type of `Date` already (and the source sql column is `date` type, not `datetime`) . The front-end users won't know how to build MDX queries, so they need to be able to just use the wizard and still get a sortable, filterable date.

Comment: According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492146.aspx, there are no separate data types for date, time, or datetime in tabular models. So maybe is everything fine already.

Comment: Yeah, on the SQL side it is `date`, in the tabular model it is `Date`, and when I import the tabular model into Excel, it is text